# Cypress doesn't type date

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have a problem where cypress doesn't type date in another part of my application.
It does type on the first part but failing to do so on the second part, even if the code is same.

This is my cypress test:

```
it.only("Inputing expiry date", () => {
  Cypress.on("uncaught:exception", (err, runnable) => {
    return false;
  });
  cy.get("[data-cy=input-expiry]")
    .type("20/01/2022", { force: true })
    .click({ force: true })
    .type("{enter}", { force: true })
    .trigger("input");
});
```

This is my react Component:

```
   <input {...props}
          className={this.getInputClass()}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          onChange={(event)=>this.onChange(event)}
          ref="myRef"
          onKeyPress={(event) => this.handleKeyPress(event)}
          onBlur={() => {
            this.setState({blur:true},this.checkValid(this.state.value));
          }}
          readOnly
          data-cy={this.props.cydatepicker}
        />
```

This is how I use my component:

```
<DatePicker
  className="expiryDBAS"
  defaultDate={
    this.state.input.expiry
      ? moment(this.state.input.expiry)
      : defaultYear
  }
  setDefaultDate={!!this.state.input.expiry}
  value={
    this.state.input.expiryDB
      ? this.buildDateValue(this.state.input.expiryDB)
      : ""
  }
  selected={this.state.input.expiryDB}
  onChange={(value) => this.updateInputDate("expiryDB", value)}
  peekNextMonth
  showMonthDropdown
  showYearDropdown
  dropdownMode="select"
  placeholder="Expiry Date"
  minDate={moment()}
  validation={[required]}
  cydatepicker="input-expiry"
/>;
```

UPDATE:

I tried to use this code but it still doesn't allow me to set the value of input field.

```
  .then(elem => {
    elem.val("20/01/2022")})
```

Comment: You have a readonly property on the input, which I guess works ok when React is in control because the setState methods will do the update. But it probably prevents Cypress and JS from directly updating, e.g `elem.val("20/01/2022")`. You can verify by removing `readonly`, and work around by exposing `this.setState` on window and calling it from Cypress with something like `cy.state('window').setState("20/01/2022")`

Comment: You would probably also need a `.trigger('change')`.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the solution which is this:

```
  it.only("Selecting expiry date", () => {
      cy.get("[data-cy=input-expiry]")
      .then(elem => {
        elem.val(expiryDate);
      })
      .trigger('change')
      .type("{esc}", {
        force: true,
       });
  });
```